# Unit testing JAX-RS (RESTEasy)

Tags: unit-testing, jax-rs, restful-authentication

I have developed a REST application server based on RESTEasy (JAX-RS).

I have a set of unit tests for each service based on `org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockDispatcherFactory`. These mock out the database calls so that I can return "canned" database responses.

Everything worked well until I added security code that checked the DIGEST Principal (`java.security.Principal`). I wrote a security interceptor that expects to retrieve the user identity of the user calling the service and verify that this user has authorization to execute the service.

I can't find any way to send in a mock Principal.

Short of disabling my security checks in my unit tests, is there any way to tell the mock server to use a mock Principal? I would rather **NOT** disable the security, because that is part of what I want to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/). Mockito enables you to mock call to any method, so it is quite easy to produce "fake", fabricated by you, Principal object. See this [example](https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-flex/branches/spring-flex-1.0-maintenance/org.springframework.flex.security3/src/test/java/org/springframework/flex/security3/SpringSecurityLoginCommandTests.java) or google "java.security.Principal mocking with mockito" for more examples.

I hope this would help, since I am not 100% sure you can apply such method in your case.